# change powerpoint 2010 cursor using vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In Powerpoint 2010 is there a way to change the cursor to the laser pointer using vba, eg by clicking on an object?
thx for reading
Art

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/powerpoint-help/turn-your-mouse-into-a-laser-pointer-HA101794344.aspx

Answer (score 3):

@Remou:  that explains how to do the job manually, but not via VBA
@Rachel: that's apparently Excel code.  The PPT application object doesn't have a Cursor property so this won't work in PPT.

You can change the pointer type but not, so far as I know, to the Laser pointer.

If you add this to your presentation then add an action setting of Run Macro:Change pointer to a shape on a slide, this'll change the pointer to Pen, Red

```
Sub ChangePointer()
    With SlideShowWindows(1).View
        .PointerType = ppSlideShowPointerPen
        .PointerColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Read http://www.ehow.com/how_7523999_change-cursor-vba.html

i think what you're looking for is Application.Cursor = xlBeam;

Comment: Application.Cursor is available in Excel but not PowerPoint